# How to make block quotes

Tags: support

I use my phone to surf this site, is it possible to make those yellow block quotes or change fonts on the mobile site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Formatting](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) help center,

> #### Simple blockquotes
>
> Add a `>` to the beginning of any line to create a `<blockquote>`.
>
> ```
> > The syntax is based on the way email programs
> > usually do quotations. You don't need to hard-wrap
> > the paragraphs in your blockquotes, but it looks much nicer if you do.  Depends how lazy you feel.
> ```

(Note: the block quote formatting is set by Stack Exchange, like yellow background on main site, but grey background on meta site. The formatting cannot be customized by a user)